# Missing number errors in a simple align environment

Tags: align

I am getting the errors "Missing number, treated as zero" and "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)" when using align environment. Here is the code

```
\begin{align*}
    e+_b e &= e \\
    e+_b f&= f+_{\neg{b}} e \\
    (e+_b f)+_c g &= e+_{bc}(f+_c g)\\
    e+_b f &= be+_b f \\
    eg+_b fg &= (e+_b f)\seq g \\
    (e\seq f)\seq g &= e\seq (f\seq g) \\
    0\seq e &= 0 \\
    e\seq 0 &= 0 \\
    1\seq e &= e \\
    e\seq 1 &= e \\
    e^{(b)}&= e\seq e^{(b)}+_b 1 \\
    (e+_c 1)^{(b)}&= (ce)^{(b)}\\
    \frac{g=eg+_p f}{g=e^{(p)}f} &\mbox{ if } E(e)=0
\end{align*}
```

I have used a lot this environment before and I do not know what is causing the problem; every time I insert an align environment, I get these errors, even if I try with examples as simple as this

```
\begin{align}
    x&=y \\
    x&=z
\end{align}
```

The description of the errors I am getting

./gkat.tex:89: Missing number, treated as zero.

>
l.89 \end{align}

./gkat.tex:89: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

>
l.89 \end{align}

EDIT: Ok, I am using some macros in a separate tex file and the errors stop when I comment the macros file; here is the code that I have in the macros file

```
\newtheorem {definition}{Definition} [section]
\newtheorem {examp}{Example} [section]
\newtheorem {theorem}{Theorem} [section]
\newtheorem {lemma}{Lemma} [section]
\newtheorem {corollary}{Corollary} [section]
\newtheorem {prop}{Proposition} [section]

\def\bf#1{\textbf{#1}}


\newcommand{\U}{\mathcal{U}}
\newcommand{\K}{\mathcal{K}}
\renewcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}
\newcommand{\D}{\mathcal{D}}
\renewcommand{\P}{\mathcal{P}}

%% operators

\newcommand{\gplus}[1]{+_{#1}}
\renewcommand{\seq}{\cdot}
\renewcommand{\iter}{^*}
\newcommand{\oA}{\text{\"A}}
\newcommand{\oB}{\text{\"B}}
\newcommand{\goplus}[1]{\oplus_{#1}}
\newcommand{\oseq}{\fatsemi}
\newcommand{\oneg}{\overline{\neg}}
\newcommand{\oun}{\"1}
\newcommand{\ozero}{\"0}
\newcommand{\lhom}[1]{\langle#1\mid}
\newcommand{\rhom}[1]{\mid#1\rangle}
\newcommand{\bihom}[2]{\langle #1 \mid #2 \rangle}
\newcommand{\equivdef}{\stackrel{\mathclap{\mbox{\tiny def}}}{\equiv}}
\newcommand{\oequal}{\overline{=}}
\newcommand{\oleq}{\overline{\leq}}


%%logic operators

\def\and{\wedge}
\def\or{\vee}
\def\then{\Rightarrow}
\def\implies{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\diamante}[1]{\langle#1\rangle}

%%logic semantics

\newcommand{\Mod}{\mathrm{Mod}(GPDL)}
\newcommand{\prgint}[1]{\llbracket#1\rrbracket}
\def\rel#1{\mathcal{R}_i\prgint{#1}}
\def\prob#1{\mathcal{P}_i\prgint{#1}}

%%equations

\def\arrayin#1{\begin{array}{rcl}#1\end{array}}
\def\just#1#2{\\ &#1& \rule{2em}{0pt} \{
        \mbox{\rule[-.7em]{0pt}{1.8em} \footnotesize{#2}} \} \nonumber \\ && }
```

But I have not redefined the algin environment, so maybe is there some command here that might be interfering?

And I am using article class and the additional following packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,url,color,eurosym,wrapfig,alltt}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{oz}
```

Comment: don't show only snippets. Show a small but complete example that can be used for a test.

Comment: Where is defined `\seq`?

Comment: The simple example produces no error when processed with `article` and `amsmath`, so some other package must be redefining `align`.  The information about your document class and relevant packages is necessary for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: Most likely some of the `renewcommand` are culprit. Don't use it blindly. (try renaming it to something unused first the error should disappear) (or `\def` for that matter, which is even more dangerous)

Comment: In particular `\or` looks *particularly* dangerous.

Comment: You use `\def`, which is highly dangerous, unless you know precisely what you're doing. In particular, redefining `\or` breaks large parts of LaTeX. By the way, LaTeX has `\land`, `\lor` and `\lnot` for the logic connectives. Redefining `\and` is also dangerous.

Comment: Thank you, it is solved now; actually it was the `\and`. I was just trying to define other names for `\wedge` and `\vee` that did not seem intuitive to mee. Now I know that I need to treat `\def`  more carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\and{\wedge}
\def\or{\vee}

\begin{document}

\author{X Y \and P Q}
\title{Title}

\maketitle

\begin{enumerate}
\item x
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item a
  \item b
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I don't get errors with `align`, but just a look at the log file for the above example should tell you that you should be ***very*** careful with `\def` ***and*** with `\renewcommand`. Never ever use the former (unless you know precisely what you're doing) and never use the latter if `\newcommand` raises an error and you don't know what the command means. For instance, doing

```
\renewcommand{\fi}{Let's try and break \LaTeX}
```

would break essentially everything.

By the way, LaTeX provides out of the box the commands

```
\land  \lor  \lnot
```

for the logic connectives as aliases to `\wedge`, `\vee` and `\neg` respectively.

Also fix

```
\newcommand{\lhom}[1]{\langle#1\,\vert}
\newcommand{\rhom}[1]{\vert\,#1\rangle}
```

because `\mid` is a relation symbol and the spacing it produces might be weird for the context.